# Strapi v4 - Querying users-permission plugin model: Error: Model role not found

Tags: strapi

I'm trying to upgrade my app from Strapi v3 to v4 and it seems there is a breaking change for querying models of a plugin.

This line of code (that works in v3):

```
const publicRole = await strapi
    .query("role", "users-permissions")
    .findOne({ type: "public" });
```

Produces the following error: "Error: Model role not found"

This is the full code:

```
async function setPublicPermissions(strapi, newPermissions) {
  // Find the ID of the public role
  const publicRole = await strapi
    .query("role", "users-permissions")
    .findOne({ type: "public" }); <---- produces Error: Model role not found

  // List all available permissions
  const publicPermissions = await strapi
    .query("permission", "users-permissions")
    .find({ type: "application", role: publicRole.id });

  // Update permission to match new config
  const controllersToUpdate = Object.keys(newPermissions);
  console.log({ controllersToUpdate });
  const updatePromises = publicPermissions
    .filter((permission) => {
      // Only update permissions included in newConfig
      if (!controllersToUpdate.includes(permission.controller)) {
        return false;
      }
      if (!newPermissions[permission.controller].includes(permission.action)) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    })
    .map((permission) => {
      // Enable the selected permissions
      return strapi
        .query("permission", "users-permissions")
        .update({ id: permission.id }, { enabled: true });
    });
  await Promise.all(updatePromises);
}
```

Is there a new way to query plugin models in version 4 to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer. Querying models in a plugin in Strapi v4 looks like this:

```
const publicRole = await strapi
    .query("plugin::users-permissions.role")
    .findOne({
      where: {
        type: "public",
      },
    });
```

Comment: how do you get the list of all models?

Answer (score 0):

after trying a lot, i used the controller name registered int the
`/src/api/user-input/controllers/user-input.js`
file as the argument of `createCoreController()` function

```
module.exports = createCoreController('api::user-input.user-input');
```

and it works!

Comment: use your own file names!